# Chrome bug: iframe rendering lines on screen when scrolling up

Tags: google-chrome, iframe

bug here: https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/chromium-bugs/eUfzp3UJDwo%5B1-25%5D

just encountered this problem, streaking up my screen on chrome, but not on firefox, or IE. anyone on a mac seen this?

Comment: Yes I have seen this in OS X as well.

Answer (score 5):

Removing the `background-color`:

```
body {
...
background-color: #fff; 
}
```

in the CSS of the HTML document which is rendered into the `iFrame` did solve the issue in my case.

Answer (score 3):

After one full day trying to solve this bug I can confirm that **there's another workaround** and it's probably an "easier" one.

**In my case these solutions didn't work.** In fact, applying them to the examples in the issue tracker of chrome   (look for them here http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=143354 ) didn't actually solve the problem. (PS: the problem is usually based on using the scrollbar and SOMETIMES in using the mouse scrolling).

Therefore I did some searches for services the worked and guess what:
**Visual Website optimizer didn't have this problem**
and they are indeed using and iframe, good job guys!

So, **what solution did they use?**
They used a fixed *height*.
(yup!)

So, take the example in the chrome issue 143354 (the one with the red background, ok?)
and change the code from

```
<html>
<body style="background-color:red">
<p>This is outside the iframe</p>
<iframe width="80%" height="50%" frameborder="0" src="./page2.html"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

to

```
<html>
<body style="background-color:red">
<p>This is outside the iframe</p>
<iframe width="80%" height="50%"  src="./page2.html" style="margin: 0px !important; padding: 0px !important; height: 286px; "></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

This will solve the problem of red lines.

To fix my webapp I needed to calculate the height on every window resize, put those margin/padding , and avoiding relative positioning on the iframe, nothing more.

Hope it helped (It almost drew me out of my mind to solve it)

Comment: It so happens that if the iframe's parent has a fixed height, the lines still persist even if the iframe's height is fixed. I solved that by making the iframe's height 1px less than the parent div's height.

Answer (score 3):

Still same problem here using Windows 7 and chrome 22.0.1229.94 except white lines appear when scrolling down, not scrolling up.
I've tried all solutions proposed but nothing seems to fix it.
Setting -webkit-margin-after and -webkit-margin-before make lines disappear when scrolling down but now it appear when scrolling up.
In chrome group forum, they say it should be fixed in 23 series but who knows...

Finally, can find a workaround (not so cool but works) inspired by some read.

Here it is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
                //to fix scrolling bug in iframe for chrome (issue: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=140447)
                if(/chrom(e|ium)/.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase())) {
                    var ibody = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];           
                    window.onscroll = function(e) { 
                        ibody.style.visibility='hidden';
                        ibody.offsetHeight; 
                        ibody.style.visibility='visible';
                    }
                }
});
```

Comment: I tried most of the suggestions in here, this is the only one that solved the issue for me!

Comment: Also, it blows my mind that `ibody.offsetHeight;` is necessary for this to work. You can't even replace that line by something else!

Answer (score 2):

Had the same issue. Resolved by setting **position** style to *relative*:

```
<iframe ... style="position: relative"></iframe>
```

Comment: There are certainly many conditions that affect the bug. Some solutions work for ones, but not the others. I'm not sure this will work for all configurations (markup, css, chrome versions, etc), but it did work for mine's. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The issue causing these visual anomalies has been confirmed fixed in the latest canary build of chrome (>= 25.0.1365.1 canary), so hopefully the chrome stable channel should have the fix fairly soon.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that it's possible to workaround this Chrome bug by shaking up the DOM a bit.

E.g. this was causing the issue:

```
  <h1>foobar</h1>
  <iframe src="..." style="border:none"></iframe>
```

... but replacing the H1 with SPAN fixed it:

```
  <span style="display:block">foobar</span>
  <iframe src="..." style="border:none"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran in to a similar problem and was able to fix it in my case by setting -webkit-margin-after and -webkit-margin-before to 0.

```
<h1 style="-webkit-margin-after:0; -webkit-margin-before:0;">foobar</h1>
<iframe src="..."></iframe>
```

Also, I initially tried replacing the H1 with a span as in Jiri's example, but the lines came back when I tried to apply a top and bottom margin of .2em to the span. Removing margins cleaned things up (I just used line-height to create some space around the header)