# Strange vertical lines after horizontal scrolling in Chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, scroll

We have a page with a table of invoices on it inside an iframe. In IE, horizontal scrolling works and looks fine. On Chrome, if you scroll over to the right, then back to the left, you see these ugly vertical lines:

[image]

This seems like a problem with doctype, but I've tried changing that and it hasn't helped. This only occurs in Chrome and only after horizontal scrolling; Firefox and IE do not show these. I'm thinking that it has to do with some HTML on the page that Chrome is rendering differently but I haven't been able to find exactly what it is.

Has anyone seen this before or have an idea on how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it's related to a Chrome bug:

https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/chromium-bugs/eUfzp3UJDwo%5B1-25%5D

A possible workaround (or hint for a workaround here):

[Chrome bug: iframe rendering lines on screen when scrolling up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12021248/chrome-bug-iframe-rendering-lines-on-screen-when-scrolling-up)