# Colored Lines in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome

In recent versions of Google Chrome, colored lines started to appear randomly as follows:

[image]

[image]

When I reload the page, it disappears most of the time, but after a while, they appear again. I believed this was Chrome's bug, but it has been around for several versions of Chrome, and I doubt Google would have left such big thing if they noticed. Is this just for me, or do you encounter this? How can it be fixed?

I am using Google Chrome Version 28.0.1500.71 on Ubuntu Linux 13.04

Comment: Have you tried updating your graphics card with the latest driver?

Comment: Seems a problem related to monitor to me..

Comment: It is not a problem with monitor because it disappears when I reload. It only happens with Chrome. And it seems to happen where there are div blocks. They are not fixed to a certain position on the monitor.

Comment: This [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13194196/1577396) might help.

Comment: Does it only appear when you have Chrome DevTools open?

Comment: I do use Developers tool, but the problem appears even when Developers tool is closed.

Comment: Open DEV Tools... Click on the Settings gear icon, check everything under `Rendering`... Close DEV, Close Chrome completely... Open again and now UnCheck all (under rendering)... close all again and see if the lines (Show paint rectangles) are gone.

Comment: @gmo I did it. I will see whether it works. Thanks.

Comment: Good luck, I hope it works for you.

Comment: So far, I don't see the problem occurring again. It seem to be working. Thanks.

Comment: Posted as an answer to help others too. I'm glad it's help ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open **DEV Tools**...
Click on the **Settings gear icon**,
Check everything under `Rendering`...
Close DEV & Close Chrome completely...

Open again and now **UnCheck all** (under rendering)...
Close all again and see if the lines (`Show paint rectangles`) are gone.